Issue in updating matplotlib, heat map is showing properly
This is the code I have used.
 %matplotlib inline
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 import seaborn as sn
 plt.figure(figsize=(10,7))
 sn.heatmap(cm, annot=True)
 plt.xlabel('Predicted')
 plt.ylabel('Truth')

I have tried updating matplotlib but after updating also, same problem

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Your code can't work, as it contains an undefined variable named cm. Further, you state "same problem" without properly explaining what that problem might be. Do you expect potential answerers to have divine mind reading capabilities?

import seaborn as sns
glue = sns.load_dataset("glue").pivot(index="Model", columns="Task", values="Score")
sns.heatmap(glue)

Output:

Reference: seaborn.heatmap
